# Windows 11 Pro installation issue. Asrock Z790 PG Lightning

Tags: installation, windows-11

I am struggling to install Windows 11 Pro on my new PC using Original USB bootable media provided by Microsoft. The thing is I cannot see the USB as boot option until I enable CSM and as far as I am concerned this is what disqualifies the platform from having win 11 installed. After I switch the CSM on, boot from USB and insert the activation key I get the "This PC doesn't meet the minimum system requirements for running Windows 11" message. I've tried different UEFI settings but this wouldn't help. Either the USB is not a boot option or I get the above message.

Intel PTT is of course enabled.
Secure Boot is also enabled.
Other HW requirements are met (i7 13th gen, 64GB RAM)

My UEFI version is: 5.01

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Windows 11 does NOT support CSM.  If you have CSM enabled then Windows 11 CANNOT boot.  Disable CSM, and then [Edit] your question, to include all updated relevant information required to answer your question.  You should make your own Windows 11 installation media using either the official tool or a third-party tool like Rufus.  **The original installation media you have is not compatible with your system.**  I am not shocked by this fact, it's happen to me personally, evident by the fact the ToS has the wrong date. The media is clearly not bootable while in UEFI mode.

Comment: On my motherboard, when CSM is enabled, two more options appear. Does this happen on your mystery machine? If so, what have you set those options to? Does your mystery machine have a "UEFI with CSM" mixed mode? That may be the solution

Comment: Can you share a picture of the UEFI boot menu (or the entry list / boot order in UEFI settings) when you boot with CSM disabled and the drive plugged in?)

Comment: @JaromandaX .. `your mystery machine` .. this killed me.  I am now dead from laughter.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - thing is, I'm stupid, didn't read the TITLE that shows what motherboard OP has :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I've tried different CSM settings, tbh I cannot recall what specific configs were that. I've managed to solve the issue though - creating installation media allowed UEFI boot with no need for CSM.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**
I managed to solve the problem by creating my own installation media. I've downloaded media creation tool from [microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) and downloaded .iso using it (this can also be done directly). I used this .iso to create bootable media with [Rufus software](https://rufus.ie/en/).

During media creation I used following rufus config:

- GPT partitioning scheme
- "UEFI (no CSM)" as target system
- Standard Windows installation

Then the media became UEFI bootable and therefore CSM was no longer needed. This was the issue causing the "This PC doesn't meet the minimum system requirements for running Windows 11" message.

Comment: Doing it directly with the official Media Creation tool would've worked fine too and would boot perfectly in BIOS/Legacy mode as well (not that it matters in 2023),